# viewing c++ methods/constructor in shared object unix/linux

Tags: c++, linux, unix, shared-libraries

I'm new to the unix/linux world and was trying to view the methods and constructor of a c++ class I compiled into a shared object.

As a test I compiled below as:  `sudo clang++ -Wall -dynamiclib dynclass.cpp -o dynclass.so`

```
class dynclass {
  public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
  dynclass () {

  }

  void  emptymethod () { }

};

int foo (void) { return 0; }
```

I then use (to view the contained functions/methods in the shared object):  `nm dynclass.so` which returns:

```
0000000000000f90 T __Z3foov
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Only the static function is visible. How can I view `emptymethod` and the constructor ?

Comment: You should avoid compiling as root with `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the constructor and `emptymethod` are declared and defined within the body of the class declaration. A function defined in the body of a class declaration is an inline function (and hence not exportable); that does not actually mean it will be inlined however.

Moving the definition of the constructor outside the class declaration results in the constructor (and destructor) being listed in the shared object's symbol table:

```
class dynclass {
    ...
};

dynclass:dynclass() {}
```

Shared object symbol table:

```
0000000000000712 T _Z3foov
0000000000000708 T _ZN8dynclassC1Ev
0000000000000708 T _ZN8dynclassC2Ev
```

Comment: This works. Strange it needs to be defined outside the class body.

Comment: actually, part of the C++ standard (methods defined within the class declaration are `inline methods`).

Comment: Well I feel foolish. :/

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code is the single .cpp file. So compiler decides class `dynclass` is not accessible to potential users of your library and hides it from ELF sympol table.

There is two ways to make class visible:
Separate declaration of class and definition (.h and .cpp files). It's IMO the best way in semantic view.
Or add into your visible code references to `dynclass` like:

```
int foo()
{
    dynclass *ptr = new dynclass();
    delete ptr;
}`
```

Comment: try it, won't make a difference.

Comment: use the OP's code with the modification in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, confused you with topicstarter.

Answer (score 0):

It's because member functions defined in a class declaration are automatically `inline`d. An inlined function's symbol, like `static` functoin's, won't be exported.

I'm not getting the extact word from the standard, but only with my experience.